# C# File.WriteAllText is not case sensitive?

Tags: c#, case-sensitive

I have a filename called **Pro-Okay.txt** and I'm trying to create a new file called **Pro-okay.txt** if it doesn't exist. I'm able to do a case-sensitive search for the file existing, but when the code moves on to **File.WriteAllText("Pro-okay.txt", "")** it overwrites the **Pro-Okay.txt** which already has information in it that I don't want overwritten. Is there a case-sensitive equivalent I could use for creating the new Pro-okay.txt file?

Here's my current code:

```
public static bool FileExistsCaseSensitive(string filename)
        {
            string name = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            return name != null && Array.Exists(Directory.GetFiles(name), s => s == Path.GetFullPath(filename));
        }

public void GetProWords(string word)
        {
            WordDataSet.Clear();
            Words.Clear();
            Frequency.Clear();
            string[] WordSet;

            string fname = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Brain\\Pro-" + word + ".txt";
            if (FileExistsCaseSensitive(fname))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText(fname, "");
            }

            TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(fname);
            try
            {
                while (txtReader.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    string line = txtReader.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Contains('~'))
                    {
                        WordSet = line.Split('~');
                        Words.Add(WordSet[0].ToString());
                        Frequency.Add(Convert.ToInt32(WordSet[1]));
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < Words.Count; i++)
                {
                    WordDataSet.Add(new WordData { Word = Words[i], Frequency = Frequency[i] });
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                txtReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I fear it is a file system issue: http://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem.

Comment: @meilke I fear your comment is the answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot easily do this on Windows because filenames in Windows are case-insensitive by default.

(Iit *is* possible to change the file system to be case-sensitive but it's a pretty major thing that you really don't want to be doing...)